# How do we create Materialized view on a table present in DB_link oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can anyone tell me how do we achieve creating a Materialized View based on an object (table) using DB_link in Oracle, We are using Oracle 12 C.

For example, I need to build an MV over this table -

```
APS.MTL_ATTR_VALUES@ODS_OF.DATATERRAIN.EDU
```

Comment: Just run `create materialized view` statement. This is illustrated in [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B__I2119713) section of docs

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ? login to your target db and issue below command.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MTL_ATTR_VALUES
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FORCE
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT * FROM APS.MTL_ATTR_VALUES@ODS_OF.DATATERRAIN.EDU;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the log in the source database and the view in the other DB.

```
-- In your source DB
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON aps.mtl_attr_values WITH
    ROWID,
    PRIMARY KEY
    INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

    --In your other DB

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv1
    REFRESH
        FAST
        ON COMMIT
AS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        aps.mtl_attr_values@ods_of.dataterrain.edu;
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way without creating log, like create a View and then create an MV based on the VIEW , because we don't have access to create logs in source DB

Comment: There's the alternative of doing it via complete refresh, but, in my experience, it takes longer than building a table from scratch. What will you be using the MV for?

Comment: it is used for joining another table that is already being used to populate the End EDW (ETL table)